# For Gradle : 7.1.3 - Flutter Android build is failing

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I recently downloaded android studio version to `Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1` and downloaded latest flutter and dart. At time of creating new flutter project it's giving build error.

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.3.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 
Framework • revision e99c9c7cd9 (2 days ago) • 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
Engine • revision 857bd6b74c
Tools • Dart 2.18.4 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like some issue with Gradle version - 7.1.3 -> I updated to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' and its works.

Comment: Removing .gradle -> cache under users  also will work

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a repository from which gradle can download the dependency.

Please, check your `build.gradle` file (application level) that contains `google` and `mavenCentral` repositories

**Build script** section:

```
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
    }
    ...
}
```

**All projects** section:

```
...
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: repositories are already available.